# Free or open-source Invoicing E-Commerce system for existing database

Tags: open-source, cms, ecommerce

I have a use case for a delivery service that requires generating invoices which may contain additional custom fields such as extra taxes, and additional product attributes etc...

I am most familiar with WooCommerce which thankfully enables creating invoices directly from the admin backend page without going through the frontend shop first but I am not sure if it is possible to display extra product attributes on the actual invoice.

Thus, I am wondering if there are existing free/open-source solutions that allow an admin user to simply:

- Import products from cvs/excel, json files etc...
- **Generate customizable invoices, possibly defining the invoice template and saving all the information in the database.**
- Displaying sales statistics based on customer infos and invoices etc...

I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions.

Thank you in advance.